# Access 2010 vba TempVars creation compile error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

> ## **Disclaimer**
>
> I've attempted the same syntax with my home copy of Access 2010 and it works the way it is supposed to, question will be edited in the next few days once I can confirm the current version of Access 2010 being used at my workplace.
>
> Issue appears to be Access related and not code related
>
> Update: My work version of Access is: 14.0.7128.5000
>
> Home version is: 14.0.4734.1000
>
> The home version works, work version does not. Still trying to figure out why.

I'm trying to create some TempVars on launch of my database and no matter where I put them, I get a compile error: "Method or data member not found", the debugger then highlights the ".Add" method right after the tempVars call.

Something like this: tempVars*.Add* (italics is the part the debugger highlights).

I've tried it in a few different functions, I put them in their own public sub, I also tried adding "Option Explicit" at the top of the code, it throws the same error no matter what.

As per the access 2010 help file, my syntax should be correct. Are there some options for the database somewhere that I'm supposed to set first?

My code:

```
Option Compare Database


'AutoExec

Function AutoExec()

    tempVars.Add "userID", ""
    tempVars.Add "userPermissions", ""
    tempVars.Add "userName", ""

On Error GoTo AutoExec_Err

    If (CurrentProject.IsTrusted = False) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox "Please enable Macros for the database to work", vbQuestion, "Please Enable Macros"
Else
    checkUser
End If



AutoExec_Exit:
    Exit Sub

AutoExec_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume AutoExec_Exit
End Sub
```

Update:

I've gone the route of creating a macro with the macro builder to set tempvars, converted it to a VBA script and tried to run the code created by the program itself and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of capitalization of the T makes me wonder you have Dim tempVars / Global tempVars / Public tempVars, etc. somewhere in your project. Search for that first. You can try using `Application.TempVars`, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I searched everything and no joy. I have been playing around with the  `Application.TempVars` as it seems to be the only way to get it to work, but then that's so long to reference them it pretty well defeats the purpose of using these in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an app I was writing using `UserID` and `UserName`. I changed the variable names to something else and it worked fine.

I think there must be system variables with the same name and so Access will not let you create them.

Try changing the variable names to something like `MyUserID` and `MyUserName`. That is what worked for me.